# Using epsilon and delta to compute a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $a>1$, let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, and define $f(x)=x^a$.  I am interesting in computing $f'(0)$ if it exists.  I claim that $f'(0)=0$.

**Attempt:** Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Suppose $0 < \lvert x-0 \rvert$ = $\lvert x \rvert$ < $\delta$.  Consider $$\left\lvert \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}-L \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{x^a-0^a}{x-0}-0 \right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{x^a}{x} \right\rvert = \left\lvert x^{a-1} \right\rvert$$  My initial thought was to let $\delta$ := min{1,$\epsilon$} so that $$\left\lvert x^{a-1} \right\rvert \leq \lvert x \rvert < \delta \leq \epsilon$$ however I think this fails if $1<a<2$.  Is there a way to define $\delta$ that avoids having to worry about the value of $a$ or should I break the problem into cases?

Comment: @ 5xum: Because $\displaystyle\left| x^{1.5-1} \right| \not\le \left| x \right|$ if $0 < x < 1$. ($a=1.5$ here.)

Comment: $\delta=\epsilon^{1/(a-1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since x belong to the set of rational numbers, you can prove rigorously that f(x) is not continuous at x = 0, and hence f'(0) does not exist.